# Animating DFS - problem using setInterval and this in Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of buttons in HTML that I want to use to animate a depth-first search by changing the button's color when it first gets visited, and then when it's finished getting visited.  I'm using a Javascript object to handle all the logic, and a recursive DFS method to build a queue like `[[animation_function, grid_coordinates], ... ]`.  Then I'm using the `setInterval` function to run through the whole queue.

The problem is it seems like the `DFSGrid` object is gone at the time that `DFSGrid.animate()` is running?  If I `console.log(this)` within `DFSGrid.animate()`, it appears `this` is refering to the Window object?  But `this` works fine in all the other methods.

I'm new to web stuff (and Javascript really) so I am extremely confused.  I've tried all sorts of different things, and I always run into some problem where `this` or that (lol) is undefined when the animation should be running.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
class DFSGrid {
    constructor(dfsGridElement) {
        this.dfsGridElement = dfsGridElement
        this.dirs = [[0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, 0]]
        this.visited = new Set()
        this.visited.add('00')
        this.queue = []
        this.idx = 0
    }

    dfs(i, j) {
        if (i > 5 || j > 3) {
            return
        }
        const coords = i.toString() + j.toString()
        this.queue.push([this.visit, coords])

        for (let d of this.dirs) {
            let [ni, nj] = [i + d[0], j + d[1]]
            let nextCoords = ni.toString() + nj.toString()
            if (0 <= ni && ni <= 5 && 0 <= nj && nj <= 3 && (!this.visited.has(nextCoords))) {
                this.visited.add(nextCoords)
                this.dfs(ni, nj)
            }
        }
        this.queue.push([this.finish, coords])
    }

    visit(coords) {
        // The grid of buttons has class selectors like:
        // <button class="c00">00</button>
        let cell = this.dfsGridElement.querySelector('.c' + coords)
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }

    finish(coords) {
        let cell = this.dfsGridElement.querySelector('.c' + coords)
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
    }

    animate() {
        console.log(this)
        let idx = this.idx
        if (idx > this.queue.length) {
            return
        }
        let [func, coords] = [this.queue[idx][0], this.queue[idx][1]]
        func(coords)
        this.idx += 1
    }
}

const dfsGridElement = document.querySelector('.dfs-grid')
const dfsGrid = new DFSGrid(dfsGridElement)
dfsGrid.dfs(0,0)
setInterval(dfsGrid.animate, 2000)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-name: Gothic Rounded, sans serif;
}

.app-content {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00AAFF, #00FFA6);
  color: gray;
  height: 100%;
}

.dfs-grid {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}
.dfs-grid button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.dfs-grid button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="app-content">
    <div class="dfs-grid">
        <button class="cell c00">00</button>
        <button class="cell c01">01</button>
        <button class="cell c02">02</button>
        <button class="cell c03">03</button>
        <button class="cell c10">10</button>
        <button class="cell c11">11</button>
        <button class="cell c12">12</button>
        <button class="cell c13">13</button>
        <button class="cell c20">20</button>
        <button class="cell c21">21</button>
        <button class="cell c22">22</button>
        <button class="cell c23">23</button>
        <button class="cell c30">30</button>
        <button class="cell c31">31</button>
        <button class="cell c32">32</button>
        <button class="cell c33">33</button>
        <button class="cell c40">40</button>
        <button class="cell c41">41</button>
        <button class="cell c42">42</button>
        <button class="cell c43">43</button>
        <button class="cell c50">50</button>
        <button class="cell c51">51</button>
        <button class="cell c52">52</button>
        <button class="cell c53">53</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this refers to the global object you've defined. An easy way to bypass it on a local level is to use an arrow function instead of a traditional function definition.

Comment: not sure what you mean... `this` should refer to the `DFSGrid` object for all of its methods, and it _does_, but not in `DFSGrid.animate()` when I call it with setInterval.

Comment: Have you tried making it an async function? Maybe it gets execute before it has the change to call the `DFSGrid.animate()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the issue I was experiencing above is described as "The `this` problem" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

When using `setInterval`, the `this` keyword for the called function will be the `window` object.  A way around this is use `Function.prototype.bind`.

```js
const startDFSAnimation = dfsGrid.animate.bind(dfsGrid)
startDFSAnimation()
```

The above will run a new version of the `dfsGrid.animate` function, but we are making sure that `this` will refer to the `dfsGrid` while it runs.

EDIT: As @Caleb Miller pointed out, this can also be solved by binding in the constructor of the class which I think is better.

```js
class DFSGrid {
    constructor(dfsGridElement) {
        // Do this for all class methods that are used by
        // setTimeout or setInterval functions
        this.animate = this.animate.bind(this)
        this.visit = this.visit.bind(this)
        this.finish = this.finish.bind(this)
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that's a good, common solution to the problem you found. Another trick for your consideration is putting the following line in the `constructor`: `this.animate = this.animate.bind(this)`. With that extra line, your old code should work. What this is doing is similar to your approach, but it's hidden away inside the class which I think is nice. Also, if you were to have multiple instances of the `DFSGrid` class, each one will have its own properly bound `animate` method, so you don't have to worry about other problems like accidentally binding to the wrong instance.

Comment: Ah, yes that's even better.  I also had to use bind for the `visit` and `finish` functions, now I can just put them all in the constructor so they're in one place.  Thank you for your input!